# I would like to know how how to generate random numbers with a specific normalized distribution funtion

Tags: python, random

Basically, if my distribution function is
f(v)= NormalDistribution(-u,sigma)+ NormalDistribution(u,sigma)

How do I define f as a PDF, normalize it and then apply some random variate command to my PDF?

Comment: You’re abusing notation pretty badly there, since the left-hand side describes a function with parameter `v` while the right-hand side has two non-functional descriptors with nary a `v` in sight. If you mean to plug in the densities on the right-hand side, it’s not a legitimate specification because it would have an area of 2. Do you mean you have random variables Z_1 ~ Normal(-u, sigma), Z_2 ~ Normal(u, sigma), and you want to know the distribution of random variable V = Z_1 + Z_2? And where does normalization (standardized scaling) enter into this?

Comment: I am saying that my PDF is the sum of 2 functions.
Then I want to normalize the PDF.
Then generata random numbers acording to the probability of my PDF

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have sum of two normalized Gaussian,

f(x) = N(x|μ,σ) + N(x|-μ,σ)

∫ f(x) dx = 1 + 1 = 2

PDF(x|μ,σ) = N(x|μ,σ)/2 + N(x|-μ,σ)/2

Because PDF is symmetric, sampling is simple: select one gaussian or another with 50% probability

Along the lines (untested)

```
import random

def sample(μ, σ):
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        return random.gauss(μ,σ)
    return random.gauss(-μ,σ)
```